# How can I overlay text on a map, without a marker or textbox, using Folium?

Tags: leaflet, folium

I want to place text anywhere, as though it were part of a tile, no text box around it, and "shown on opening" (ie, `show=True`).

I don't see any text overlays in the documentation: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html

Pure Leaflet appears to allow something like the "sweet static label" on display here:
http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.label The code for this is:

```
var m = L.marker([-37.785, 175.263], {draggable:true}).bindLabel('A sweet static label!', { noHide: true })
        .addTo(map)
        .showLabel();
```

That's better. But I would like text only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used Folium, but since I'm familiar with Leaflet, I was able to quickly find what you are looking for: `folium.features.DivIcon`. Description says: *Represents a lightweight icon for markers that uses a simple div element instead of an image*.

Since content of `DivIcon` is a simple HTML `<div>` element, you can put anything you want in it.

Comment: Thank you. I had been searching for "text" in the docs. And for anyone who needs it, here is a working example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400769/numbers-in-map-marker-in-folium